# Datepicker for mdbootstrap not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the mdbootstrap (https://mdbootstrap.com/) template for my website and i m trying to use datepicker within my page, but it is not working.
Please anyone tell me the reason for this.

Comment: please provide us more details. What's your version of MDB? Do you use free or pro version? Or maybe do you use one of MDB's templates pack? What's your os & browser?

Comment: I am using MDB version 3 free version. Linux OS and chrome browser.And I am trying to use jquery datepicker.

Comment: Datepicker is a premium component which is available only in MDB Pro. It means you cannot use it for free